# How does JS closure work in this example?

Tags: javascript, closures

I would really love to understand a very detailed understanding of the code mentioned below. TIA.

```
var globalValue = 'Global Val';
var ref1,ref2;
function outer(){
    var outerValue = 'Outer Val';
    function inner(){
        var innerValue = 'Inner Val';
        function innermost(){
            var innermostVal = 'Inner most Val' ;
            console.log(globalValue + '\n' + outerValue + '\n' + innerValue);
        }
        ref2 = innermost;
    }
    ref1 = inner;
}

outer();
ref1();
ref2();
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) already? What details exactly do you not understand? What parts *do* you understand?

Comment: Was not able to understand where do closure actually come in action, when does a closure get created. The answer below was helpful!

Comment: It comes in action when it is called, it does created when the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

## Closure - A protective bubble

Let's break up the question that has been asked, knowing that you have the patience to read the detailed answer. :)

Below, we define a function `outer` and `var globalValue` at Global level.

Inside the `outer` function we define function `inner` and `outerValue`.

Inside the `inner` function we define `innerValue`. To cross verify that `inner` function has access to all the variables we log `globalValue, outerValue and innerValue`. It logs all the three values.

However, it will fail if we try to access `innerValue` anywhere else than the lexical scope of that variable.

```js
    var globalValue = 'Global Val';
    function outer(){
        var outerValue = 'Outer Val';
        function inner(){
            var innerValue = 'Inner Val';
            console.log(globalValue + '\n' + outerValue + '\n' + innerValue);
        }
        inner();
    }

    outer();
```

Now, we will see have a closer look to closures. 
So, in the example above we have quite proved the sneakiness of the `inner function`. 
Now, if we would invoke inner on global level, it would return an `error` because it is defined locally inside the `outer` function. The work around for that is to declare a global variable `ref` and store `inner` as a reference.

While, JS engine execution stage starts. It invokes outer(), and it creates an execution context for the `outer` function. It creates `execution stack` for the `outer` function.

And before the execution stack for function `outer` ends it assigns the value of `inner` in global var `ref`. 
The execution stack for function `outer` has ended right now.

Even though the `global execution stack` is back in action. We have access to all the variables of the function `outer` and `inner` through the reference of `inner` function stored in global variable `ref`. There you go, that is a *`closure`*.

```js
var globalValue = 'Global Val';
var ref;
function outer(){
    var outerValue = 'Outer Val';
    function inner(){
        var innerValue = 'Inner Val';
        console.log(globalValue + '\n' + outerValue + '\n' + innerValue);
    }
    ref = inner;
}

outer();
ref();
```

Below we are adding one more level to it. Here there is another function `innermost` which has been defined inside function `inner`. However, there has to be a chain to make the `closure` work.

Hence, the function value `innermost` is first passed to `ref2` and then in the `outer` function. The value of `inner` is passed to `ref1`. This keeps the bubble from bursting and we are able to access all the variables even while invoking the function using reference at `global level`.

```js
var globalValue = 'Global Val';
var ref1,ref2;
function outer(){
    var outerValue = 'Outer Val';
    function inner(){
        var innerValue = 'Inner Val';
        function innermost(){
            var innermostVal = 'Inner most Val' ;
            console.log(globalValue + '\n' + outerValue + '\n' + innerValue);
        }
        ref2 = innermost;
    }
    ref1 = inner;
}

outer();
ref1();
ref2();
```

Comment: [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36) Eric Elliott has explained the concept of closures beautifully!!